# How to form schema for mongoDB for this json object?

Tags: json, mongodb

I am trying to form mongodb schema for the below json object:

```
{

        "103s": {
            "a1": {
                "b": "dfdf",
                "c": "fgfhh"
            },
            "a2": [
                {
                    "b1": 0,
                    "c1": "sdsd"
                },
            ],
            "a3": "1) qw \n" +
                "2) df \n" +
                "3) cv \n" +
                "4) fg",
            "a4": "1) asd \n" +
                "2) fgh"
        },
        "34": {
            "a1": {
                "b": "dfdf",
                "c": "fgfhh"
            },
            "a2": [
                {
                    "b1": 0,
                    "c1": "sdsd"
                },
            ],
            "a3": "1) qw \n" +
                "2) df \n" +
                "3) cv \n" +
                "4) fg",
            "a4": "1) asd \n" +
                "2) fgh"
        }

}
```

I came up with the below schema:

```
   error: {
    "a1": {
      "b": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "c": {
        "type": "String"
      }
    },
    "a2": {
      "type": [
        "Mixed"
      ]
    },
    "a3": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "a4": {
      "type": "String"
    }
  }
```

I cannot decide what to put for the `error` in above schema. Shall I form a mixed type object then map it? I am not sure as it does not give right results then. Moreover, I also need to be careful about which format will this be fetched in from the db at front-end on html and angularJS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the above mentioned schema is correct. It is while inserting that we can actually modify the key of the document we are trying to insert. There, we can provide an attribute called `_id` and set user defined `id` here. MongoDb takes that `_id` and set it for this document. So the schema is :

```
{
    "_id" : String,
    "a1": {
      "b": {
        "type": "String"
      },
      "c": {
        "type": "String"
      }
    },
    "a2": {
      "type": [
        "Mixed"
      ]
    },
    "a3": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "a4": {
      "type": "String"
    }
  }
```

This resolved the issue for me and I was able to insert the records in MongoDB with my own custom ids.